# web autoplay policy change resuming context doesn't unmute audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autoplay, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm working on a progressive web app which is mainly used on desktop and android to play music. On PC, everything works fine. On Android, it suddenly stopped working. After some research I found [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio) update regarding an autoplay policy change in chrome.

The gist is that you cannot just play media anymore without a user interaction.

Before this update I had my AudioContext which gets created `onload` and afterwards is just used. This doesn't work anymore.

The update posts states this:

> An AudioContext must be created or resumed after the document received a user gesture to enable audio playback

So I made some adjustments to `.suspend()` and `.resume()` the context accordingly `onPlay` and `onPause` of my application.

On PC this still works, on Android it doesn't. Am I missing something?

**Edit 1:**

I found [this](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/autoplay) site stating the following:

> Under the new policy media content will be allowed to autoplay under
>   the following conditions:
>
> a) The content is muted, or does not include any audio (video only)
>
> b) The user tapped or clicked somewhere on the site during the browsing
>   session
>
> c) On mobile, if the site has been added to the Home Screenby the user
>
> d) On desktop, if the user has frequently played media on the site,
>   according to the Media Engagement Index

I understand this to be true if one of those matches. In my case b) and c) are fulfilled. 
So I guess this *should* work?

Comment: @Kaiido Hm I see. I guess I have to see how I can do this synchronously, because until now I've worked with vuex modules which, in my case, trigger an action asynchronously. Maybe I could add a synchronous initialization action or something similar.. 
Can you provide sources for the two different autoplay? maybe this will help to clear my confusion

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just my own experience, and it may not be correct... (re-reading your error message tends to prove I am wrong) They changed a lot of things around these policies, and the docs are hard to stick together. But once again from experience, reacting inside the user-gesture always works, on all UAs.

Comment: some discussions about this issue: chrome https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/vuYEHSeqonM/JpeLkiJABgAJ and specs https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/836

Comment: So I was wrong, it seems they do use the same policy for AudioContext and MediaElement.autoplay. Now I don't know why it doesn't work for you, maybe the fact that you try to use the AudioContext throws an error which blocks the normal behavior even after the user granted the required gesture? You could prevent it by checking your AudioContext's `state` property. If set to `"suspended"`, don't attempt anything.

Comment: thank you for your input, I appreciate it. I'm pretty sure I do not use the context before the user made an input, because I only start loading audio sources from a remote host when the user clicked 'play' on something. once the loading is done it gets decoded, the context resumed and then played. If the user presses pause i stop the node and suspend the context until he clicks play again.

Comment: @Kaiido you're right. I managed to resolve the issue by creating the context AFTER the user interacted with the page. I still do it asynchronously, so this doesn't make a difference. Would you like to write a proper answer? I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call resume() on the audio context on a user action event such as button click.  I am guessing your problem was the location of where you called context.resume() was not on a user interaction event.  You can't just call it from onLoad.

Sample code:

```
// Existing code unchanged.
window.onload = function() {
  var context = new AudioContext();
  // Setup all nodes
  ...
}

// One-liner to resume playback when user interacted with the page.
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  context.resume().then(() => {
    console.log('Playback resumed successfully');
  });
});
```

Docs describe it here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio